# How do you cleanly pass column names into cursor, Python/SQLite?

Tags: python, sqlite, cursor

I'm new to cursors and I'm trying to practice by building a dynamic python sql insert statement using a sanitized method for sqlite3:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("db.sqlite")
cursor = conn.cursor()
list = ['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'value1', 'value2', 'value3']
cursor.execute("""insert into table_name (?,?,?) 
values (?,?,?)""", list)
```

When I attempt to use this, I get a syntax error "sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?"" on the line with the values. This is despite the fact that when I hard code the columns (and remove the column names from the list), I have no problem. I could construct with %s but I know that the sanitized method is preferred.

How do I insert these cleanly? Or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The (?, ?, ?) syntax works only for the tuple containing the values, imho... That would be the reason for sqlite3.OperationalError

I believe(!) that you are ought to build it similar to that:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO {tn} ({f1}, {f2}) VALUES (?, ?)".format(tn='testable', f1='foo', f1='bar'), ('test', 'test2',))
```

But this does not solve the injection problem, if the user is allowed to provide tablename or fieldnames himself, however.

I do not know any inbuilt method to help against that. But you could use a function like that:

```
def clean(some_string):
    return ''.join(char for char in some_string if char.isalnum())
```

to sanitize the usergiven tablename or fieldnames. This should suffice, because table-/fieldnames usually consists only of alphanumeric chars.

Perhaps it may be smart to check, if

```
some_string == clean(some_string)
```

And if False, drop a nice exception to be on the safe side.

During my work with sql & python I felt, that you wont need to let the user name his tables and fieldnames himself, though. So it is/was rarely necessary for me.

If anyone could elaborate some more and give his insights, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I appreciate the insight - I can understand not needing to sanitize the field names (I plan to dynamically generate them through another internal class method in the same class), I just was trying to grok the best way to do both insertion of field names and the values. I'm thinking now (after reading your response) of using the %s method to generate the initial string, which will include the ?. And then just insert that whole string... I'll get back to you on whether that worked.

Comment: Indeed. If I code for my own sake, I tend to be lazy and do something like this: `"SELECT * FROM hashtable WHERE %s=?;"`

Answer (score 2):

First, I would start by creating a mapping of columns and values:

```
data = {'column1': 'value1', 'column2': 'value2', 'column3': 'value3'}
```

And, then get the columns from here:

```
columns = data.keys()  
# ['column1', 'column3', 'column2']
```

Now, we need to create placeholders for both columns and for values:

```
placeholder_columns = ", ".join(data.keys())
# 'column1, column3, column2'

placeholder_values = ", ".join([":{0}".format(col) for col in columns])
# ':column1, :column3, :column2'
```

Then, we create the INSERT SQL statement:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO table_name ({placeholder_columns}) VALUES ({placeholder_values})".format(
    placeholder_columns=placeholder_columns,
    placeholder_values=placeholder_values
)

# 'INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column3, column2) VALUES (:column1, :column3, :column2)'
```

Now, what we have in `sql` is a valid SQL statement with named parameters. Now you can execute this SQL query with the data:

```
cursor.execute(sql, data)
```

And, since `data` has keys and values, it will use the named placeholders in the query to insert the values in correct columns.

Have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) to see how named parameters are used. From what I can see that you only need to worry about the sanitization for the values being inserted. And, there are two ways to do that 1) either using question mark style, or 2) named parameter style.

Comment: Funny thing is I started with a dictionary object and then broke it down to a key list and a value list and then just concatenated them to get my list. My only concern is really the loss of the sanitation that the ? method gains. As I mentioned I could construct the insert string using a similar method, but I don't see how your method would sanitize the data.

Comment: @user2833273: I updated my answer so it uses named parameters which will ensure sanitization of values. I have also added the link to the documentation for the same. As far as the column name sanitization is concerned, that is not supported either by question mark or by named parameters. They are only used for values.

Answer (score 1):

So, here's what I ended up implementing, I thought it was pretty pythonic, but couldn't have answered it without Krysopath's insight:

```
    columns = ['column1', 'column2', 'column3']
    values = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
    columns = ', '.join(columns)
    insertString=("insert into table_name (%s) values (?,?,?,?)" %columns)
    cursor.execute(insertString, values)
```

Comment: needs a bit more `str.format()` + snake_case and a bit less %-formatting + camelCase before it's pythonic ;)

...doesn't solve the injection problem either, ofc (which makes it somewhat strange that you linked the Bobby Tables comic on the other answer), but that's alright if you're in control of all possible inputs.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, as a relatively new user, I really appreciate the support of the community. Casing aside, it does actually solve the injection problem. Even if the function was called, because it's using the "?" syntax in the insert statement it won't actually take executable sql. But again, thanks for the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import sqlite3
    conn = sqlite3.connect("db.sqlite")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
## break your list into two, one for  column and one for value
    list = ['column1', 'column2', 'column3']
    list2= ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
    cursor.execute("""insert into table_name("""+list[0]+""","""+list[1]+""","""+list[2]+""")
    values ("""+list2[0]+""","""+list2[1]+""","""+list2[2]+""")""")
```