# How can I use a variable to reference a column in Python SQLite?

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to replace a certain column based on user input in Python SQLite.
I've tried multiple things, but here's what my code looks like right now so you can understand what I'm trying to do.

```
c.execute("UPDATE commtable SET (?)=(?) WHERE guild=(?), (arg1, arg2, guild)")
```

Except I can't use (?) for a column... So how can i use a variable where text should be, in this situation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you cleanly pass column names into cursor, Python/SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37404048/how-do-you-cleanly-pass-column-names-into-cursor-python-sqlite)

Answer (score 0):

The variables shouldn't be inside the SQL command being executed.

`c.execute("UPDATE commtable SET (?)=(?) WHERE guild=(?)", (arg1, arg2, guild))`

If you go to [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_keywords.asp), there is a good reference for SQL if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic SQL only concerns values. The table and column names must be present in the SQL query when the engine processes it. That means that you have to build a query containing the column name, and then pass the true variables in the execute method:

```
c.execute(f"UPDATE commtable SET {arg1}=? WHERE guild=?", (arg2, guild))
```